# cancelAll() and cancel() don't dismiss my notification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, notificationmanager, notification-channel

I am facing this problem for a long time now, I have an application with many functions, one of them is the alarm

My notification just stays there and never disappears **although I am calling `cancelAll()` / `cancel()` from the notification manager, also I have `autoCancel` set to `true`**! It also stays clickable, I just need it to disappear after actions are triggered!

*(I am testing this on an emulator with Android Studio, not sure if this could be the problem)*

I searched a lot an tried so many things and nothing worked so I would appreciate the help :)

I have set my notification as follow:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// ...

private void initNotification() {
    setNotificationChannel();

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), notificationChannel.getId());

    Intent click_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingtonePlayingService.class)
            .putExtra("intent_action", "click")
            .putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", alarmRequestCode)
            .putExtra("ID", alarmId);
    PendingIntent click_pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, MainActivity.getRequestCode(), click_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent dismiss_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingtonePlayingService.class)
            .putExtra("intent_action", "dismiss")
            .putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", alarmRequestCode)
            .putExtra("ID", alarmId);
    PendingIntent dismiss_pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.getRequestCode(), dismiss_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent snooze_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingtonePlayingService.class)
            .putExtra("intent_action", "snooze")
            .putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", alarmRequestCode)
            .putExtra("ID", alarmId);
    PendingIntent snooze_pending = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.getRequestCode(), snooze_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    dismissAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.small_delete,
            "Dismiss", dismiss_pending);
    snoozeAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.bell_ring,
            "Snooze", snooze_pending);

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm On!")
            .setContentText("Click the notification to dismiss")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(click_pending)
            .setDeleteIntent(click_pending)
            .addAction(dismissAction)
            .addAction(snoozeAction)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}

private void showNotification() {
    notificationManager.notify(alarmRequestCode, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void setNotificationChannel() {
    channelId = "alarm_channel_id";
    channelName = "alarm_notification_channel";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
```

When the actions buttons are pressed this is the part of code triggered:

```
if (action != null) {
        switch (action) {
            case "click":
                alarmManager.cancel(cancelPendingIntent);
                notificationManager.cancelAll();
                player.stop();
                changeAlarmValuesToOff();
                break;
            case "snooze":
                alarmManager.cancel(cancelPendingIntent);
                notificationManager.cancelAll();
                player.stop();
                setNewSnoozeAlarm();
                break;
            case "dismiss":
                alarmManager.cancel(cancelPendingIntent);
                notificationManager.cancelAll();
                player.stop();
                changeAlarmValuesToOff();
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

***I also tried using `cancel()` using the `alarmRequestCode` which is the unique ID used for both alarm and notification and still didn't work***

Everything is working fine, the actions perform as desired only that the notification stays right there and stays clickable and performing actions as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot of the notification]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is not in the notification settings itself, the problem is that the notification is running in a `Service` class. While the service is still running the notification cannot be dismissed.

**How I solved this:**
In the service class, after the action is performed *(Where I was calling `cancelAll()`)* I call `stopSelf()`instead.
Then override `onDestroy()` and call `cancelAll()` in it instead!

Cheers